# CSS font only works in some Django templates extended from same base

Tags: css, django, templates, django-templates

I'm in the middle of creating a fairly complex site using Django, and I've noticed a weird problem.

All of my templates extend the same base template (`base.html`). That base template looks (something) like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fonts.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/webStyleSheet.css' %}">
        {% block head %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        {% block header %}
        <div class="header">
            <h1><a href="/">Title</a></h1>
            <ul class="nav-bar">
            <!-- nav bar content here etc etc-->
        </div>
       {% endblock %}
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

<!-- js relevant to the nav bar etc etc -->

{% block script %}
{% endblock %}
```

My `fonts.css` file declares my font-faces, for example:

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Overpass Mono';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Overpass Mono Regular'), local('OverpassMono-Regular'), url('../fonts/OverpassMono-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/OverpassMono-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}
```

And in my `webStyleSheet.css` I implement those fonts like so:

```
:root {
    --font-secondary: 'Overpass Mono', monospace;
}
/*the class I use for the nav-bar elements*/
.menu-button { 
    font-family: var(--font-secondary);
}
```

As I said, I extend this base in all of my templates. The problem arises in that on some of the extended templates, I get the correct font (Overpass Mono) but on some of the templates, I get the default (monospace). The template is getting `webStylesheet.css`, but not rendering the right font. Normally, I would think that this is just an issue with relative paths to get to the font. However, both extended templates are siblings. The relevant file structure looks something like this:

```
site
--views.py
--urls.py
--static
----css
------fonts.css
------webStyleSheet.css
----fonts
------OverpassMono-Regular.woff
------OverpassMono-Regular.ttf
--templates
----html
------template1.html (font works)
------template2.html (font doesn't work)
```

Both templates are extended like this:

```
{% extends "html/base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load tags %}

{% block head %}
    <!-- some included css and scripts only relevant to this template -->
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- content -->
{% endblock %}
{% block script %}
    <!-- js -->
{% endblock %}
```

The only difference that I can discern between the two is how the template is rendered. One of the templates is rendered with a view in my `views.py`, and the other one is rendered directly with `TemplateView.as_view(templatename='html/template1.html')`. Like so in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^url1/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='html/template1.html'), name='template1'),
    url(r'^url1/url2/$', views.view2, name='view2'), # (return render(request, 'html/view2.html', contextVals) from views.py)
]
```

There are some other weird artifacts that occur, too. One of the other fonts that I am using (for the main header in the nav-bar) works in all the templates! I've also had other functions work on template1, but not on others: like Boostrap funtions `.tab()` and `.modal()`, which might be related and have to do with how the includes are handled in this inheritance structure.

Does this have to do with how the template is rendered? What else might be causing the issue, and how can I go about fixing it? It's driving me up a wall! Any guidance is appreciated.

(Note, I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088003/css-works-only-in-one-of-three-templates-when-extended-from-the-same-template) but it's not quite the same problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, after some more digging, I finally found the answer.  It turns out that the issue was here:

```
:root {
    --font-secondary: 'Overpass Mono', monospace;
}
/*the class I use for the nav-bar elements*/
.menu-button { 
    font-family: var(--font-secondary);
}
```

I realized that the font that it was using wasn't actually a default monospace font: it was a different font entirely. Well, as you would have it, one of the other stylesheets I was including uses the same variable name for the font (`--font-secondary`). At least that means that it's an easier fix than originally thought, but it definitely does not explain my other issues with Bootstrap functions. Regardless, this fixes the main problem in the question.